# Date popup picker issue in opera

Tags: css, html, drupal-7

I have website(in developing), everything seems to work fine, except date popup picker in opera. In other browsers both inputs are active, but in opera, first one looks fine, but the other one, is just like not exists(or like an image)
Here is website where you can check the code
http://stagealpha.dyndns.org/plasma/articles
Any ideas what can cause this bug?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<input type="date">
```

which will give you a datepicker that is supported by every browser, and if a new browser doesn't support it, it defaults to text....

If you would like to see what it looks like, check out http://wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html